# Writing to text files in Java

Tags: java, text-files, dataoutputstream

I have a method that writes a string to a text file using a `DataOutputStream` and the `.writeBytes(String)` method.  If I write a string with a newline character, for example `"I need \n help!"`, the new line is not displayed in notepad or other basic text editors.  However, it does show up in WordPad, MS Word, etc.  Why is this and can I fix it?

Comment: Sort of related, try a better editor like Notepad++, http://notepad-plus-plus.org/ . I frequently work with file formats (ER7/HL7) which are sensitive to line endings (\n vs. \r vs. \r\n) and non-printing ASCII charaters, which this editor is capable of displaying to see what is really there. It's free, try it and see if it helps you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly by using real text editors, which Notepad isn't.

You need to write system-specific newlines if you're not going to use a text editor that understands different flavors, or filter the file through something that does the conversion for you.

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

This will give you an OS-specific line separator. It's less useful than you think.

```
System.out.printf("%n");
```

This does the same (and is available in `String.format` as well); also less useful than you think. It's more an editor thing, since any file could exist on any system, edited with any editor.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `System.getProperty("line.separator");` instead of directly using \n.

Comment: you can also use \r\n instead. It covers all your bases and doesn't screw up anything. Saves a couple milliseconds every thousand lines, so there isn't a big difference.